# Concurrent HTTP requests from within a single Sidekiq worker?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, sidekiq

I'm trying to interact with Google's Calendar API.  My tests so far show response times of 5-10 **seconds** to insert a single event, and I may need to export thousands of events at once *[don't ask]*.  This seems likely to spam the heck out of my queues for unreasonable amounts of time.  (95% of current jobs in this app finish in <300ms, so this will make it harder to allocate resources appropriately.)

I'm currently using Faraday in this app to call other, faster Google APIs.  The Faraday wiki suggests using Typhoeus for parallel HTTP requests; however, using Typhoeus with Sidekiq was deemed ["a bad idea"](https://twitter.com/mperham/status/477479180725022720) as of 2014.

Is Typhoeus still a bad idea?  If so, is it reasonable to spawn N threads in a Sidekiq worker, make an HTTP request within each thread, and then wait for all threads to rejoin?  Is there some other way to accomplish this extremely I/O-bound task without throwing more workers at the problem?  Should I ask my manager to increase our Sidekiq Enterprise spend?  ;)  Or should I just throw these jobs in a low-priority queue and tell our users with ridiculous habits that they'll just have to wait?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's reasonable to use threads within Sidekiq job threads.  It's not reasonable to build your own threading infrastructure.  You can use a reusable thread pool with the `concurrent-ruby` or `parallel` gems, you can use an http client which is thread-safe and allows concurrent requests, etc.  HTTP.rb is a good one from Tony Arcieri but plain old net/http will work too:

https://github.com/httprb/http/wiki/Thread-Safety

Just remember that there's a few complexities: the job might be retried, how do you handle errors that the HTTP client raises?  If you don't split these requests 1-to-1 with jobs, you might need to track each or idempotency becomes an issue.

And you are always welcome to increase your Sidekiq Enterprise thread count.  :-D

Comment: Thanks, Mike! Always happy to send you more money (especially when it's not my money). :)

Comment: In Sidekiq wiki is stated that Typhoeus crashes a lot so I understand you don't recommend to use it with Sidekiq? is this statement still valid?